# SQL How to add value when IF return true from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvfBM.png)

I have two table: table log and table pengunjung

At table log there is 2 column named jumlah_pengunjung_masuk and jumlah_pengunjung_ditolak int data types

at table pengunjung there is 1 column named status_lolos boolean data types

my question is how to auto update value in table log

when status_lolos = true -> update column jumlah_pengunjung_masuk values +1 where tanggal=tanggal_tercatat

when status_lolos = false -> update column jumlah_pengunjung_ditolak values +1 where tanggal=tanggal_tercatat

Comment: Please cut and paste the text instead of posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE log 
JOIN pengunjung ON log.tanggal = DATE(pengunjung.tanggal_tercatat)
SET jumlah_pengunjung_masuk = jumlah_pengunjung_masuk + CASE WHEN status_lolos THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    jumlah_pengunjung_ditolak = jumlah_pengunjung_ditolak + CASE WHEN NOT status_lolos THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
-- WHERE ???
```